# 3d array as double pointer, freeing memory after usage

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array, memory-management, free

First off, let me say that everything works like a charm, but the memory deallocation. Maybe it's pure coincidence that I do not have any problems and my basic understanding is wrong.

Also, please refrain from telling me "Use `std::vector` instead" or the like, as I want to learn and understand the basics first!

Now to the code:

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test(const unsigned int xDim, const unsigned int yDim, const unsigned int zDim);
    ~Test();

private:
    unsigned int xDim, yDim, zDim;
    TestStructure **testStructure;
    void init();

    int to1D(int x, int y, int z) { return x + (y * xDim) + (z * xDim * yDim); }
}
```

cpp:

```
Test::Test(const unsigned int xDim, const unsigned int yDim, const unsigned int zDim)
{
    this->xDim = xDim;
    this->yDim = yDim;
    this->zDim = zDim;
    this->testStructure = new TestStructure *[xDim * yDim * zDim];

    init();
}

void Test::init()
{
    for(int x = 0; x < xDim; x++)
        for(int y = 0; y < yDim; y++)
            for(int z = 0; z < zDim; z++)
            {
                this->testStructure[to1D(x, y, z)] = new TestStructure(
                        x - xDim / 2,
                        y - yDim / 2,
                        z - zDim / 2);

...
}
```

Now for the destructor I tried two ways:

```
Test::~Test()
{
    for(int x = 0; x < xDim; x++)
        for(int y = 0; y < yDim; y++)
            for(int z = 0; z < zDim; z++) {
                free(this->testStructure[to1D(x, y, z)]);
            }
    free(this->testStructure);
}
```

and

```
Test::~Test()
{
    for(int a = 0; a < xDim * yDim * zDim; a++) {
        free(this->testStructure[a]);
    }

    free(this->testStructure);
}
```

I am pretty sure the second is like the first, but In both cases I get:

> ==3854==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: alloc-dealloc-mismatch (operator new vs free) on 0x62100008e900

Where are my mistakes? Throw them at my face and let me learn!

edit: Basic mistake: use `delete` (for `new`) instead of `free` (for `malloc`).

Replacing the `free`s above with `delete`s leads to:

> ==4076==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: new-delete-type-mismatch on 0x60600002c300 in thread T0:

edit2:

Pardon me, with `delete[]` for the array part it leads to:

> ==4138==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x62100008e8f8 at pc 0x000000480b3d bp 0x7ffc5bcbc0f0 sp 0x7ffc5bcbc0e0

**edit3/SOLUTION**: Did it the wrong way. This seems to work:

```
Test::~Test()
{
    for(int a = 0; a < xDim * yDim * zDim; a++) {
        delete(this->testStructure[a]);
    }
    delete[] this->testStructure;
}
```

Big thanks @SomeProgrammerDude

Comment: What you allocate with `new` you must free with `delete`. And `new[]` matches `delete[]`. And `malloc` with `free`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks, if I change to delete I get > ==4076==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: new-delete-type-mismatch on 0x60600002c300 in thread T0:

Comment: The elements in the array, the ones you allocate with `new` you must delete with `delete`. The array itself, which you allocate with `new[]` you must delete with `delete[]`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude want to add this as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: Please, note that You don't really need to use `to1D(x, y, z)` in `init()`. You can use an extra index, say `k`, something like `testStructure[k++] =  ...`. There's no need for all those `this->` too and consider using [member initializer lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) for the constructor.

Comment: Thanks Bob but considering the syntax I hope that the compiler will take care of that as I prefer a more Java like syntax